# Getting the contents of a file with PHP FTP

Tags: php, apache, ftp

I am trying to get the contents of a file on a remote FTP server through PHP.  Looking at all the docs though it doesn't appear possible to do this without first saving the transferred file to disk and then opening it.

Is there any way of reading the file straight into a variable or buffer without having to save it to disk first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can use [FTP stream wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) too

```
$content = file_get_contents('ftps://user:password@example.com/pub/file.txt');
```